# Problems uploading to an AWS bucket via SDK with Route 53 alias

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

So, I have a website that's using AWS S3 to host images. Images need to be uploaded automatically as the server gets updated on an hourly basis.

I've just created a new bucket with a Route 53 A Record so we can have images hosted at images.website.com instead of website-images.s3.aws.amazon.com

The problem now is that the uploader returns an error saying that the bucket doesn't exist.

I'm using AWS SDK for PHP 1 (haven't upgraded yet), but everything else is current. Is the problem just that the new bucket name has periods in it (images.website.com)?

Does AWS SDK 2 fix this? Is there a fix for this?

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: You did name the bucket in all lowercase, yes?  If you can get to the raw error message, it should contain the name of the bucket your code is trying to access, `<BucketName>foobarbazzzz</BucketName>` as part of the error, which might help you troubleshoot.  Also, is the bucket working, as verifiable by whether you can upload files to the bucket via the console and download them again?  S3 [had a problem a few weeks ago](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=494026) where some newly-created buckets were not really created.  Hopefully not a repeat, but worth mentioning.

Comment: It's all lowercase. The bucket works, uploading and downloading files via the console is not a problem.

Comment: The bucket was also created some time ago, so it being a newly-created bucket would not affect the uploads in the traditional sense.

Comment: How about the <BucketName> in the API response? If that isn't coming back wrong, then it shouldn't be the old SDK, but if it is coming back wrong, then it might be.

Comment: Can't check that till Monday.

Comment: The point of failure is on `$s3->if_bucket_exists("images.website.com")` which returns false, despite the bucket existing.

Comment: Do you even need to call that method?

Comment: Need? Maybe not. Good practise? Almost certainly.

Comment: I disagre,  if it's static code always calling the same bucket name on a bucket you control...That's arguably just a time waster, and at least worth trying without in the interest of troubleahooting.

Comment: The code is developed to be able to use multiple bucket names. It's a dynamic system.